# Adding an unknown number of imageviev(each of them has absolute position on X and Y) to the page

Tags: android, imageview, layout-inflater

There is a task to place on the page of viewPager required number of images with absolute position. Number and positions are obtained from another app, so are unknown. How to implement it? Got any ideas?

Comment: what you have tried uptill so far ?

Comment: Have not yet started work on it. I'm quite new to android development. I think of using absolutelayout and layoutInflater to add images to absoluteLayout. I can not even guess whether thinking right way. I do not ask for example code, need just approximate description of the solution